# Upload ICS calendar file to Google Calendar

Tags: email, ical

I read my email in Emacs, and every now and then I receive an ICS file as an attachment, usually in a confirmation message for an event I've signed up for.  That's very kind of them, because it means I don't need to enter the event into my calendar manually.  It looks like this in the message buffer:

```
Attachment: [4. text/calendar; foobar.ics]...
```

I want to import that event into Google Calendar.  Currently I handle those files like this:

- Save the ICS attachment from within message-mode (move point to the attachment and hit `o`)
- Open Google Calendar in my web browser
- Click the cogwheel, and select "Settings" in the menu that appears
- Open the "Calendars" tab in the settings page
- Click the "Import calendar" link
- Select the ICS file in the file upload input control
- Select which calendar to add the event to
- Click the "Import" button

It gets tedious after a while. How can I import the event into Google Calendar directly from Emacs, without all these intermediate steps?

Comment: There's a command line interface to Google calendar which you​could use. It's not very efficient but for small calendar files it should be enough. Then you'll have to wrap this in an Emacs command. I hope someone will do that.

Comment: @YoungFrog Good idea. It wasn't very hard :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a command line interface to Google Calendar called [gcalcli](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli). You can install it using pip:

```
pip install gcalcli
```

In order to import calendar files, gcalcli requires the vobject library to be installed:

```
pip install vobject
```

The first time you run gcalcli, it will launch a web browser in order to obtain an oauth token, which it will save in `~/.gcalcli_oauth`.  `list` is a good command to use:

```
gcalcli list
```

---

Now that `gcalcli` is installed, let's configure Emacs to use it.  Add the following entry to your `~/.mailcap` file (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
text/calendar; /path/to/gcalcli --calendar 'Calendar Name' import %s
```

"Calendar Name" is the name of the calendar you want to import calendar entries into, as listed by `gcalcli list`.

To make Emacs pick up the new entry, type `M-x mailcap-parse-mailcaps`.

To import a calendar file, move point to the `[4. text/calendar; foobar.ics]` part, hit `.`, and enter `view externally` as the "action".  Emacs will run `gcalcli` and display the output in the message buffer — hopefully `New event added: https://....`.